# What is the difference between connections and data sources in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I have two excel workbooks each with one sheet of data. I want to create visualizations by blending data. First, I tried to import both workbooks using add connection option within single data source. Later, I tried to import one workbook into one data source and added a new data source to import another workbook. I was able to create the visualizations I want in both approaches. But is there any difference between the two approaches?

Comment: Importing multiple sources of data into a single connection allows you to define the relationships between the tables in the sources as part of the connection. This often allows faster, better and more complex relationships between the tables. This matters more for DB sources than flat excel tables where blending won't be very different. But blends are sometimes very limiting for complex data sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following difference:

A Data Connection represents the database server information required to log in (connect) to a database, and it also contains the relation for the underlying data. The relation may be a single table, a multi-table join, or a Custom SQL query that yields a result set.

A Data Source represents the view of this data connection as it appears in the 'Data' pane on the left side of the Desktop product interface. This includes any changes you make to the fields, such as their caption, aliases, geographic role, default aggregation, etc. Additionally, a Data Source represents fields which do not exist in the underlying Data Connection, such as calculated fields, ad-hoc groups, sets, and Tableau-generated fields such as 'Measure Names', 'Measure Values', 'Latitude (generated)', and 'Longitude (generated)'. Collectively, this is sometimes referred to as the data model.

I hope this helps,

You can read more on: https://community.tableau.com/thread/254130

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I am curious to know about the functional difference between the two rather than the aesthetic part. For instance, to add the 2nd data source, when do I use - add new connection vs. add new data source? Based on what do I decide?

Comment: Using the logic mentioned above, If you have 2 data sources which are connected in any database like SQL or AccessDB then you should directly make the connection rather than adding two different data sources and then joining them in Tableau environment. Here processing in Tableau's environment will get optimized ultimately will result in faster refresh of the visuals.
Hope this helps in your decision.